# PATCH Call with $batch changeset

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap, sap-gateway

How does the SAP NetWeaver GateWay know which row in a table to update using PATCH?

Let's say I have a form, and update the 'description' for an item, how would SAP know to update the description for the item the form is for?

The form has the KEY but this is not passed back to the PATCH call because it's not been changed...

Comment: Why do you say the key is not passed in the PATCH request? You're wrong, see [this PATCH example](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#update). If you used a batched OData request, the PATCH requests are multiparts inside the request body (see [batch](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/advanced-tutorial/#batch)).

Comment: If the key is passed back, how do I get it?  It's no where in CHANGESET_PROCESS

Answer (score 0):

The `PATCH-method` works by calling the `GET_ENTITY-method` for your entity, merging existing data with the data you want to patch, and then running the `UPDATE-method` that is provided with the merged data.

You can see the implementation of this in the following method:

`/IWBEP/IF_MGW_APPL_SRV_RUNTIME~PATCH_ENTITY`

Comment: The changeset_process method should be able to retrieve the data as follows:
`* Get Changeset Data and create CHnageset Request
    mo_changeset_helper->get_changeset_data(
      IMPORTING
        et_changeset_data = ct_changeset_data
    ).`

Comment: I can't access mo_changeset_helper inside CHANGSET_PROCESS?